# VTC tallies messed up?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro

As I was working through the /review VTC queue earlier today, I noticed my VTC count was up past 250 or so. I just went back to the queue to use up today's VTC quota, and saw my rally was down around 220 or so.

What happened?

Update: possibly a load balancer caching issue? On refresh, my VTC tally is now bouncing back and forth between 221 and 260 or so.

Comment: VTC = vote to close, right? (just checking). The count isn't cached, so in theory, it should always be accurate. I've never observed this behavior, and it isn't repro'ing now, so I've added the [status-repro] tag. We'll keep an eye on it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Emmett Yep, that's correct. I should note that this behavior was observed using iPad/Safari, so perhaps it's doing some aggressive caching that it shouldn't have been doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a caching tier issue... Did the problem "fix itself" after 30 minutes? If so, that's it.

Comment: Yes, that was it. The inconsistency cleared up at some point overnight.